# How can I remove multiple elements from a list?

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [2,5,61,7,10]
list1.remove(list1[0:len(list1)-1])
print(list1)
```

I want to remove all elements from that list but it shows me syntax error.
Any idea how can I remove all elements and print the final result like `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove **all** list items just use the in-built `.clear()` function:

```
>>> list1 = [2,5,61,7,10]
>>> list1.clear()
>>> print(list1)
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Ok but also are there any avalabile options to remove a specified range for example (0:2) ; not just all elements

Comment: your question did say 'I want to remove **all** elements' but if you also want to remove only a range of elements this can be done using iBug's answer below to use the _slicing_ approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements from a list, you can use the slice assignment:

```
list1[:] = []
```

But with `list.remove()`, you can only do it one-by-one:

```
for item in list(list1):
    list1.remove(item)
```

Note I created a copy of `list1` with the for loop because it's dangerous to modify what you're iterating over, while it's safe to modify the list while iterating over a copy of it.

To remove some of the items:

```
for item in list1[0:3]:
    list1.remove(item)
```

Or just better yet, use slice assignment:

```
list1[0:3] = []
```

Comment: @Barmar Pretty sure they do. It's iterating over a (shallow) copy of the original list, so there's no such issue of modifying a running list.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see the copies.